# Domain names that start with a number

Tags: regex, rfc

I'm writing a regex for validating domain names. I'm looking at RFC 1035 section [2.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) (starts on the bottom of page 7) and in the section it states:

> They must start with a letter, end with a letter or digit, and have as
> interior characters only letters, digits, and hyphen.  There are also
> some restrictions on the length.  Labels must be 63 characters or
> less.

But I've seen domains all over the place that have digits as the leading character? Is there another RFC that I am missing that changes this?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/638260/is-it-valid-for-a-hostname-to-start-with-a-digit

Comment: RFC 1123 updated it to allow leading digits.

Comment: The RFC you link to has a banner which enumerates all the RFCs which update it. (Many of them cover other aspects, of course.) The historic rationale was that sites like 112.com (number service) weie pushing into existence, and there was no technical reason to prevent that.

Comment: Then post an answer instead of closing a question ugh